# Why zero to the zero power is 1?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, computer-science

The google calculator say that $0^0=1$. I'm confused. It's well-known $0^0$ is undefined.

Comment: Unfortunately, the selected answer in that duplicate question is wrong. There are plenty of reasons to define $0^0=1$. There are no reasons to define it to be other values. There *can* be reasons to leave it undefined, especially in computer calculations when dealing with computer floating points, because then $0.0$ is always an estimate, so you can get into trouble.

Comment: Some people like to say that $0^0$ is undefined, some people (including me) like to define $0^0=1$, because it's consistent with everything regarding powers with integer exponent.

Comment: One good reason: So it's clear that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nt^n$ means what we want it to mean when $t=0$.